# NHibernate unique constraint remove if duplicate

Tags: sql, .net, nhibernate

Is there a way to tell nHibernate to remove the duplicate value on a row's column that is uniquely constrained when updating a row with a duplicate value.

For example (OtherId and Animal is compositely unique constrained)

```
Id | OtherId | Animal
------------
1  | 1       | Dog
2  | 1       | Cat
3  | 1       | Bear
4  | 2       | Dog
```

Updating Id 3 to Dog, should result in this

```
Id | OtherId | Animal
1  | 1       | NULL
2  | 1       | Cat
3  | 1       | Dog
4  | 2       | Dog
```

**EDIT:**

I was able to solve my problem by creating an unique index in my table

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [Id_OtherId_Animal_Index]
ON [dbo].[Animals] (OtherId, Animal)
WHERE Animal IS NOT NULL;
```

This way, I prevent insertion of duplicate (1, Dog) and still allow (2, Dog). This will also allow multiple (1, NULL) to be inserted.

Next, based on Frédéric's suggestion below, I edited my service layer to check BEFORE insertion if it will be a duplicate. If it will, then NULL the animal column of which would be uniquely constrained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer has been outdated by substantial [changes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42518799/revisions) in OP question**

I am quite sure there is no such feature in NHibernate, or any other ORM.

By the way, what should yield updating Id 3 to Cat after having updated it to Dog?

```
Id | Animal
1  | 
2  | 
3  | Cat
```

If that means that Id 1&2 now have the empty string value, that will be an unique constraint violation too.
If they have the `null` value, it depends then on the db engine being ANSI null compliant or not (null not considered equal to null). This is not the case of SQL Server, any version I know of, at least for the case of unique indexes. (I have not tested the unique constraint case.)

Anyway, this kind of logic, updating a row resulting in an additional update on some other rows, has to be handled explicitly.

You have many options for that:

1. Before each assignment to the `Animal` property, query the db for finding if another one has that name and take appropriate action on that another one. Take care of flushing right after having handling this other one, for ensuring it get handled prior to the actual update of the first one.
2. Or inject an [event or an interceptor](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html) in NHibernate for catching any update on any entities, and add there your check for duplicates. Stack Overflow has examples of NHibernate events or interceptors, like this [one](/a/42486861/1178314).
   But your case will probably bit a bit tough, since flushing some other changes while already flushing a session will probably cause troubles. You may have to directly tinker with the sql statement with `IInterceptor.OnPrepareStatement` by example, for injecting your other update first in it.
3. Or handle that with some trigger in DB.
4. Or detect a failed flush due to an unique constraint, analyze it and take appropriate action.

The third option is very likely easier and more robust than the others.

Comment: Thank you for this, I actually just thought about what if something were to update both columns to empty string or null then wouldn't that trigger a unique constraint violation too, but I'm going with your #1 approach and handle this in the service layer then, sounds more like business logic now.